# transfer value from gridview to textbox , is it possible?

Tags: c#, gridview, textbox, data-transfer

i have a credit request registration page. well its just a normal registration page that includes name, address, company, and credit request (money). after which, it is viewed from a gridview in the admin page(viewcredirequest.aspx) here is the code of the aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" 
            SortExpression="EmailAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyAddress" HeaderText="CompanyAddress" 
            SortExpression="CompanyAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="IncomeRange" HeaderText="IncomeRange" 
            SortExpression="IncomeRange" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="CreditRequest" 
            SortExpression="CreditRequest" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IslandGasAdminFM"] != null)
        {
            bindgrid();
            Label1.Text = "- Finance Manager";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
        }
    }
    public void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests ", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

My DB values are as follows: LastName, FirstName CompanyName, EmailAddress, CompanyAddress, IncomeRange, Creditrequest and ContactNumber. The Creditrequest is taken from a dropdown list.

well what i want is to transfer the credit request value from the gridview to a textbox in my viewprofile.aspx. and another thing, what i have in mind is that when i click a link on a specific row, the credit request value will then be available on the viewprofile of that of the username? please help me to get some references or any idea on how to do this. thank you!

its like when you approve the credit request, the credit request value will be passed on by the profile page of that username through a textbox.

Comment: How do you want a column values to be displayed in a single textbox!!

Comment: only the credit request value is what i want to be transferred to another webpage in a textbox @Vanest